# Parsing invalid JSON string to JSON2 in java script

Tags: javascript, json

I have a an invalid json string as below which i wanted to convert to JSON. I want to get rid of eval(). JSON.parse() is throwing an exception. Is there anyother way to do this?

```
 "{user:'C3DC5FF987ACB5C8CB7ADF9D774775FA', recover:[{client:'call',
call:{CTI_TELEPHONE_CALLED:'sip:217812@UKAvayatest.fnfis.com;user=phone',
CTI_CALLER_TELEPHONE:'0031205849948',
CTI_TIME_IN_QUEUE:'Created:10:59:48 03/08/15;Queued:11:00:42
03/08/15;Answered:11:00:46 03/08/15', CUSTOMER_NBR:'817',
SORTCODEACCTNO:'NO_VALUE', IDVS:'3', SKILL:'SBY SAV SE E Blocked Acct
D', CDN_NAME:'SBY SAV SE E Blocked Acct D',
CONTACT_ID:'ukbiataaep-2015141090031-5', TP_CALL_TYPE:'NO_VALUE',
TP_CALL_STATUS:'NO_VALUE'},
contactId:'ukbiataaep-2015086103648-14'},{end:'end'}]}"
```

Comment: What is your question? Are you having trouble understanding why it is invalid? Are you trying to programmatically repair it? Are you generating it yourself (in which case you should show the code that is generating it so we can tell you how to fix that)?

Comment: This is generated at the server and pushed to the front end through atmosphere framework. I am trying to convert it to JSON. I should not use eval().

Comment: I think you can use regex to make your false JSON to right JSON. I don't think there is magic way to do it. You need to analyse what's wrong, match and replace.

Comment: @vijaykandady — So you should look at the code on the server that generates it and fix that.

Comment: @Quentin I cant convert it to JSON on the server since we are using the atmosphere framework to deliver the message to client. Atmosphere is taking only string. It is in a .jar

Comment: @vijaykandady — JSON is a text format. If you can only hand over a string then make the string formatted as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Well the rules this invalid JSON is violating are just missing quotes around key names (like `"name":`) and use of single quotes around string literals (like `'call'`). To fix these you would need to walk through this string inserting quotes or replacing single quotes as you go (while keeping track of if you are inside a string literal). A generic solution to this would likely be very complicated and yield little benefit over just calling `eval()`.